# How to make user signed out from facebook when he logs out of facebook application on a php website

Tags: php, facebook, session, web-applications, destroy

I have the following code which runs when user clicks on logout button:

```
if ($_GET['m'] == 'logout'){
session_destroy();
$facebook->destroySession();
header("Location: /");
```

}

The user is logged out of facebook app but is still online on Facebook. How to sign out the user from facebook too? Thanks

Comment: Yes thats a pretty old issue, you may need to use JS library for logout function which works pretty well. Or may be you can use `getLogoutUrl` for logout with PHP SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Use php sdk of facebook and paste below code in your file

```
    require_once 'facebook/src/facebook.php';
    $facebook = new Facebook (array(
         'appId'  => '*****************',
         'secret' => '****************************'  
));

 $user = $facebook->getUser();
$homeurl = 'index.php';//url you want to redirect after facebook logout


if ($user) 
{
      $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>$homeurl));
}
```